# Bash script that deletes files in a specific directory?

Tags: bash, directory

I'm starting to write bash scripts and I would like to do the following:
a script that deletes the contents of a directory specified in the second argument of the invocation. Like this: example.sh /home/A
Any suggestions?
Thanks!!

Comment: If some of this answers is right for you, please mark answer as "accepted".

Comment: Is `rm -rf dir` not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Literally `find /home/A -delete`. Or `find "$@" -delete` if you want to put it in a script and clean multiple directories.

Answer (score 0):

please use following code

```
#!/bin/bash

yellow=`tput setaf 3`;

info() {
    echo "${yellow}INFO  : $@ ${reset}";
}

main () {
    if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
        S_DIR=$1;
        rm -rf "$ACTION";
        info "main : delete folder.";
    else
        info "main : please enter folder path.";
    fi
}

main $@;
```